# Can you @import default css variables? (spicifically, I'll use @use)

Tags: css, sass

I want to make a file with all the variables, but they are going to be default CSS variables.

Can they be exported to the main SCSS file (by `@use`)?

Don't ask why I prefer default ones over SCSS.

Comment: Why include SCSS here at all, if you only want CSS solution? Also there is no such thing as "default variables". Variable values do cascade though. And there is something called "default values", is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean ":root {}".
I wanted to use scss, with css vars.
It worked (except I needed import for that)